# What is an ideal residue, and the square of an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In Zariski's "The Concept of a Simple Point of an Abstract Algebraic Variety", in section 2.1, he refers to elements being '$m$-residues', where m is the maximal ideal of a quotient ring $p(W) / p(V)$. He later defines a vector space $m / m^2$, and defines elements as being "$m^2$-residues". What are these concepts?

Comment: It looks like his use of the word "residue" is what today is called a "coset".

Comment: This doesn't seem like such an obstacle -- he's telling you exactly what these things are. In both cases it's "elements of this quotient". In Hartshorne these quotients would be called "residue field" and "Zariski cotangent space", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This means that, if you consider the prime ideals $\mathfrak p=I(V)$ and $\mathfrak q=I(W)$, one defines the ring of (polynomial) functions on $V$ and on $W$:
$$R(V)=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak p,\quad R(W)=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak q.$$
As $W\subset V$, $\mathfrak p\subset \mathfrak q$. He also defines the relative ring:
$$R(W/V)=\bigl(R(V)/p(W/V)\bigr)_{p(W/V)},\quad\text{where}\quad p(W/V)=\mathfrak q/\mathfrak p, $$
in other words the *localisation*:
$$\bigl(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak p\bigr)_{\mathfrak q/\mathfrak p}$$
It is a *local ring*, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak q/\mathfrak p\bigl(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\mathfrak p\bigr)_{\mathfrak q/\mathfrak p}$, which we may also denote $\mathfrak mR(V)_\mathfrak m$.

An $\mathfrak m$-residue is just a congruence class modulo $\mathfrak m$, i.e. an element of this ring.

$\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is an $R(V)/\mathfrak m$-vector space; its elements are elements of the ring $R(V)/\mathfrak m^2$, i. e.  congruence classes mod. $\mathfrak m^2$.

Comment: As $V \subset W$, it shoul be $q \subset p$?.

Comment: @NguyenDangSon: You're right. I guess it was a typo. I've checked in the original paper, and $W$ is an irreducible subvariety of $V$.'Tis fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!